# Transferring IIS settings IIS6.0 (Windows Server 2003) to ISS7.5 (Windows Server 2008)

Tags: iis-6, iis-7.5

Does anyone know how to transfer IIS settings from IIS6.0 (Windows Server 2003) to ISS7.5 (Windows Server 2008)? Please note: I don't want to transfer any websites, just the IIS6 settings for the time-being.

Comment: I'm going to follow this guide http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/427/migrate-a-web-site-from-iis-60-to-iis-7/

Answer (score 0):

Your follow-up comment is good.  WebDeploy is the way to do migrations between IIS6-6, 6-7 and 7-7.  http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy